# Clarify git stash for me in switching branches

Tags: git

I've been working on branch A. My work there is not finished, but I need to switch to branch B for a while. It looks like `stash` is the command to use. I've found a number of references showing how to use stash to save your changes, but I'm a bit confused. All of the references say something like, when you're ready to go back, just do `git stash pop`. They don't, however, tell me if I need to switch back to branch A before doing that, though.

So, do I manually go back to branch A before running stash pop, or do I stay in branch B, and the actual act of running stash pop will send me back to branch A where I left off with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `git stash pop` will apply the stashed changes to the code that you currently have checked out. So if you want to apply them to your original branch, you'd need to `checkout` that branch before popping the stash.

Comment: Thank you. That's what made sense to me, but none of the guides I found said it explicitly, so I wasn't sure.